# Angular 6 compilation error

Tags: angular

Angular 6 "angular.json" could not find bootstrap.min.css in the directory as and error popups during the execution.

I have attached the screenshots of configuration files and error:-

Error :- [image]

Project.Json Configuration file: [image]

Angular.Json file: [image]

Node_Modules file: [image]

Error says "Module not found" but required file very much present in its directory as i can see it.

What is the problem then?!!!

Answer (score 0):

remove `../`  before `node_module` path,put  `"node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"`

node_modules is at the same level as angular.json file,puting ../ means search outside the project folder

Comment: Thanks for the reply anyhow i got it resolved, though i have already tried  that once...